# string is removing \t in the text while i want everyting behind the backslash

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping

I have a parameter passed through my url which is as followed:

`eu\test5`.

When I print this string it says `eu est5`, it is replacing the `\t`.

How can I make sure my string is not exaping anything?
I want to grab all the data after the backslash, so I have the value `test5`.

```
string user = "eu\test5"; 
int backslashPos = user.IndexOf("\\");

label2.Text = user.Substring(backslashPos);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an `@` in front of the string or use `"\\"`.

```
string user = @"eu\test5";
string user = "eu\\test5";
```

`\` is used for escape sequences, which is used for several commands inside a string. Like `\n` for a New Line

Using an `@` ignores all escape sequences in a string.

Here is a list of all escape sequences [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: It's a common problem, which normally occurs with File IO (directories)

Answer (score -1):

\t is an escape sequence representing a set of spaces. So the result you are getting is obvious.

Comment: Technically, it's an escape sequence representing a tab character.